# C++ objdump use and disassembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, memory-address, disassembly, objdump

On a linux server, the command would be

$ objdump -t exercise11 > symbol_table.txt

The intention is to find the memory address and size (in bytes) for the three global variables in a program.
The second portion is equivalent to

$ objdump -S exercise11 > disassembly.txt

The intention here is to search the text file and find the instruction for assigning a valuable to a variable.

My problem is that I am using Visual Studio 2017 on a local machine. I am in the visual studio command prompt but either I need something different or I am misunderstanding what I am reading in the output files. I have also used dumpbin commands but it did not seem to produce the correct information, either. Could you please show me how to do this in Visual studio and how to find the information I am searching?

Comment: "I have also used dumpbin commands but it did not seem to produce the correct information, either." How did you use it and what did you get as a result?

Comment: It seems dumpbin and objdump commands produced the same result. I used modifiers like -SYMBOLS and other commands that was listed with the help function, but none of it produced a memory address or the machine code for the function doSomething()

Comment: 3 downvotes without comments? Now I remember why I quit using this site.

Comment: Afaik, memory addresses are assigned when linker composes all object files. They are not delivered within a particular obj file.

Comment: I know this works in netbeans on a linux terminal, I have done it. I just can't figure out how to do it in visual studio.

Comment: It's such a simple question... I'm completely confused on how no one knows and the question is only down voted without comment. You shouldn't be able to down vote without a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the project's property pages. Click Linker. Click debug and there are a couple options for generating a Map file which will allow you to see the memory address of variables and such.

0004:00000000       ?variable1@@3HA            00420000     Excercise11.obj

The question itself is not hard, but finding the right option in Visual Studio instead of NetBeans was problematic.